# Drupal-6/PHP  to Java data retrieve

Tags: java, php, web-services, drupal, xml-rpc

I have a site, where Admin is already developed in Drupal.  Admin used to add component, module, data with the help of Drupal.

Now I need to make this site Front-end with the help of JAVA.
Now I need complete front-end data in Java and it should worked as it is worked in Drupal-php site.

What is the best way out to solve the issue[ Developed the Front-end of the site]. XML-RPC , web-service or some thing else.

Please help me.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? To me, it seems like you have some sort of administration panel, powered by Drupal, and that you are now trying to rewrite this in Java. If this is the case, I don't think one can propose a "best way" to solve the issue without knowing what the backend is and how it works...

Answer (score 1):

The [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) or [Views Datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) may help you to access content (ie. data) managed on a Drupal site from a Java front-end. They both allow you to expose content from Drupal as XML or JSON. Services provides REST API to access the data over HTTP, while Datasource will allow you to quickly build bulk list of contents as structured data.

Direct access to Drupal database from the Java application should be avoided. Drupal modules manage their own tables (through the database and schema API). And modules like the CCK will even update the structure of their tables when their configuration is changed. There is usually no guarantee that a module's table structure won't change over time.